# Javascript (JS) application working on Chrome but not on mozilla firefox/safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, safari, mozilla

Here is my problem, i created a web application where you need to load a file (image) then it appears in a canvas after a resizing in order not to excess 1500 px. Then i use a canvas zoom programmed like this (another canvas where i zoom on the mouse position):

```
var x1, wdth1, psx1, wdth2, y1, heg1, psy1, heg2;
function drawZoom(x, y) {
    $('#zoom').css({
        'left': x - (parseInt($('#zoom').css('width')) / 2),
        'top': y - (parseInt($('#zoom').css('height')) / 2)
    });
    // console.log([x,y]);
    $('#zoom').show(function () {
        if (x < 25) {
            x1 = 0;
            wdth1 = (x + zoom_level / 2) * ratio;
            psx1 = (25 - x) * 2;
            wdth2 = 100 - psx1;
        } else if (x > width_canvas - zoom_level/ 2) {
            x1 = (x - zoom_level/ 2) * ratio;
            wdth1 = (width_canvas - x + zoom_level/ 2) * ratio;
            psx1 = 0;
            wdth2 = 100 - 2 * (x + zoom_level/ 2 - width_canvas);
        } else {
            x1 = (x - zoom_level/ 2) * ratio;
            wdth1 = zoom_level* ratio;
            psx1 = 0;
            wdth2 = 100;
        }
        if (y < 25) {
            y1 = 0;
            heg1 = (y + zoom_level/ 2) * ratio;
            psy1 = (25 - y) * 2;
            heg2 = 100 - psy1;
        } else if (y >= height_canvas - zoom_level/ 2) {
            y1 = (y - zoom_level/ 2) * ratio;
            heg1 = (height_canvas - y + zoom_level/ 2) * ratio - 1;
            psy1 = 0;
            heg2 = 100 - 2 * (y + zoom_level/ 2 - height_canvas);
        } else {
            y1 = (y - zoom_level/ 2) * ratio;
            heg1 = zoom_level* ratio;
            psy1 = 0;
            heg2 = 100;
        }
        // console.log(heg1);
        zoomctx.fillStyle = "black";
        zoomctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        zoomctx.drawImage(canvas, x1, y1, wdth1, heg1, psx1, psy1, wdth2, heg2);
    });
    zoomctx.beginPath();
    zoomctx.moveTo(0, 50);
    zoomctx.lineTo(100, 50);
    zoomctx.moveTo(50, 0);
    zoomctx.lineTo(50, 100);
    zoomctx.closePath();
    zoomctx.stroke();
}
```

then i save the positions of the click and use them in order to calculate a distance etc.... (another story)
so i have a reset button, when you start clicking and fail one of the 4 click needed you can restart, it deletes all the points and restarts the fonction.

ISSUES :

-Chrome: works like a charm, no problem, nice zoom, smooth navigation, restart works perfectly etc....

-Firefox: i have a black circle on the left top corner (it's the zoom but it's all black, not working), it doesn't move, i can click and restart but i can't see where i click and the process after clicking doesn't work.

-Safari: the image appears well, the zoom is ok when i first load the image, i can click 4 times and the rest of the program works fine but if i restart then the zoom is like shifted when i put my mouse somewhere and the zoom doesn't show me the right place.

so i have no issue on chrome, and 2 different issues on safari and mozilla firefox, no error in the console.

i'm a beginner so i dont know if the is some constraints as the "webkit" in CSS for JS.

Tell me if you need more info ! Thanks !

Comment: Some free advice; try to uniform your code. I see camel casing and underscores in your variable names. You also mix dutch with english, it makes reading your code harder than it should be

Comment: i changed the variable names to english (it was in french) and try to explain the issue clearly, thanks you.

Comment: Could you include a live example (with DOM nodes etc).

Comment: as i told you i'm a beginner, i don't know what are DOM nodes and what you mean by a 'live example' ? i saw that DOM are like an object in JS but i dont really how it can help you

Answer (score 0):

I found what was going on with firefox, it was just an update problem. my friends tested it out with their version of firefox and all was ok si i updated my firefox (thought it was doing this alone but apparently not) and it worked fine. I'm gonna try with safari if this is the same problem or not

Answer (score -1):

Canvas drawing isn't supported in Firefox, but there are Mozilla specific alternatives.  See https://caniuse.com/#search=Canvas

As far as your issues with the positioning after resetting the zoom in safari, please post your reset button functionality. Chances are, you are missing some reinitialization of your position/coordinate tracking.

Comment: *Canvas drawing isn't supported in Firefox,* Hum what? It is since FF version 2.

Comment: i think it's supported,on the link i can see that canvas drawing is 'unknown' on mozilla firefox but 'not supported ' on chrome, but it's works well on chrome so maybe that are fake info ? i dont know but i really think that canvas is supported by most of browser